# how to display the number of created records in the query if you have only the first record and the last one

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I have code with which to create records in the range between the first and last. To do this, I only need to specify the first record and the last. Here is the code:

```
SELECT    SUBSTR (:P5_FIRST_SEALS, 1, 1) ||
          LPAD(TO_CHAR (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P5_FIRST_SEALS, '\d+$')) + level - 1), 8,'0') 
          AS x_SEAL_NUMBER
     FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P5_LAST_SEALS, '\d+$'))
             - TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P5_FIRST_SEALS, '\d+$'))
             + 1;
```

For example, I said the first number A14602157 and the last A14602167. (10 entries) in response to the query would be:
[image]
After I find what records I need to make, I write a log in the table, where I specify the first record, the last record, and the date. Here's how I get data from the log table:

```
SELECT      FIRST_SEALS,    LAST_SEALS,DATE from SEC_TRANSFER_SEALS
```

Is it possible to make this query in such a way that not only the first and last record of the range and the number of added records appear?
I would like the answer to the second request to be this :

```html
SELECT      FIRST_SEALS,    LAST_SEALS,DATE , count(FIRST_SEALS between LAST_SEALS)  from SEC_TRANSFER_SEALS
```

```
A14602157 , A14602167 , 07-06-21 , 10
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Im edit)

Comment: Your requirement is still not clear. How exactly your result should look alike.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Following the example I mentioned above, I created 10 records, and in the table SEC_TRANSFER_SEALS I wrote only the last record and the last one. I would like when I make request from tables of logs to see not only the first and last record but also the counter of the added records

Comment: @AnkitBajpai SELECT      FIRST_SEALS,    LAST_SEALS,DATE , count(FIRST_SEALS between LAST_SEALS)  from SEC_TRANSFER_SEALS

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Something like that

Answer (score 0):

You have all info on your Apex page (that **is** Apex, right?), so just reuse it:

```
SQL> select :P5_FIRST_SEALS   as first_seals,
  2         :P5_LAST_SEALS    as last_seals,
  3         trunc(sysdate)    as datum,
  4         :P5_LAST_SEALS - :P5_FIRST_SEALS + 1  as total_number
  5  from dual;

FIRST_SEALS LAST_SEALS DATUM       TOTAL_NUMBER
----------- ---------- ----------- ------------
          1         10 07-jul-2021           10

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks, but there is one problem, if for example I want to add records from A14602157 to A14602160, this command does not work.

Comment: The code I demonstrated in the question adds not only numeric entries in the range, but also letters-numbers

Comment: We know only what you tell us. Therefore, my code answers question you initially posted.

Comment: can you help me (given the comment that I added, ie to also count from A14602157 to A14602160)?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to take into account my comment?

Comment: Remove leading "A" and try it yourself.

Comment: The letter as the first symbol is fundamental! This code for adding seals from the first to the last, in the number of seals is always the first letter. And the code which I entered in a question, solves this question, that is if I specify (A14602157 to A14602160) the list of seals (4 pieces) will show me. But in the query added from the table I want to see not only erush and the last but also their number. And I can't write this request in any way.

Comment: I really need your help in this matter)